# Select query from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hello I am having a hard time trying to SELECT all of the information I need from two tables, the following two tables are:

```
Person: |id|fname|mname|lname|   and Related: |id1|id2|relationship|
```

and I want the following to be displayed back from the SELECT query:

```
|id1|fname(of id1)|id2|fname(of id2)|relationship|
```

SO the Related table has two id's that are FOREIGN KEYS to Person(id), and I need to
SELECT id1, (id1's first name), id2, (id2's firstname), and the relationship.

I've tried something like this and a few other SELECT queries but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
SELECT p.fname, r.id1, r.id2, r.relationship
FROM Person p, Related r
INNER JOIN Related ON first.id = r.id1 
INNER JOIN Related ON second.id = r.id2;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're joining on `Related` thrice.  You only need to join once, and you need to join on `Person` again.

```
SELECT id1, p1.fname, id2, p2.fname, relationship
FROM Person p1
JOIN Related ON (p1.id = id1)
JOIN Person p2 ON (id2 = p2.id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked it will be the accepted answer as soon as I can accept!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a website for you (w3schools) and it should have all the information you need for the `SELECT` function you're trying to get. Hope this helps:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Yeah I actually know w3schools and I have searched through things and I've done other queries that worked based upon things I learned from there...but this query I just couldn't get to work but thanks for the info!